# Qt sending keyPressEvent

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, key-events, qkeyevent

I want to append chars to `QLineEdit` by sending KeyEvent.
I'm using code like this:

```
ui.myEdit->setFocus();
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   QKeyEvent keyPressed(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, 'a', Qt::NoModifier);
   QWidget::keyPressEvent(&keyPressed); // or
   //QApplication::sendEvent(QApplication::focusWidget(), &keyPressed);
}
```

Why there is no change in `myEdit`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the change the text of `QLineEdit` simply by :

```
ui->myEdit->setText(ui->myEdit->text().append("a"));
```

But if you really want to change it by sending `QKeyEvent` you can try this :

```
QKeyEvent * eve1 = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_A,Qt::NoModifier,"a");
QKeyEvent * eve2 = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyRelease,Qt::Key_A,Qt::NoModifier,"a");

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)ui->myEdit,(QEvent *)eve1);
qApp->postEvent((QObject*)ui->myEdit,(QEvent *)eve2);
```

Comment: Thank you, had to use fourth parameter, like this: QKeyEvent ev(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, '  ', Qt::NoModifier, 'a');

Comment: Why are the casts required `(QObject*)( ... )` and `(QEvent*)( ... )` ?

Comment: No, this is different behavior then OP. As demonstrated, `setText` always appends a character. OP's example will insert the character at QCursorPos (or whatever it is called). OP's insert can occur at the beginning, middle or end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not wise.

1. Setting the focus yourself may annoy more than one user which loose focus from one UI element for the other.
2. By calling `keyPressEvent` directly you are skipping many layers of processing from the framework. Only misbehavior await down this path.

To reply to

> I want to append chars to QLineEdit

You can obtain the line edit text, modify at your will and set it back.

```
QString currentText = ui.myEdit->text();
QString toappend    = "aaaaaaaaaa";
QString nextText    = currentText + toappend;
ui.myEdit->setText(nextText);
```

or one line

```
ui.myEdit->setText(ui.myEdit->text()+mystring);
```

Comment: Actually I'm using insert method, but I wanted to use keyPressEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesizing a key press event to append characters to a line edit is asking for endless trouble. You'd need to retain the state of the control to ensure that you are in fact *appending* characters. If the cursor is not at the end, you'll be inserting or prepending characters. If any modifiers are active, you may cause the widget to act as if, say, a clipboard shortcut was activated. Say if you "append" an X while Ctrl/⌘ is held down, you'll cause any selected text to disappear from the line edit.

In other words: if you want to append something to a textedit, simply append it, don't synthesize keystrokes.

```
lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text() + "appended");
```

That's it. To do it *properly* via appending keystrokes requires about a page of code, and even then it can't but rely on Qt's implementation details.