# Receive Escape-Event in QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, key-events

This is a bit of a beginners question but I don't find the solution.

I'm using an own object that inherits from `QLineEdit` and reiceves numbers as input (which works smoothly now).

Now I want to receive an event, when the user presses the Escape-button. This does not happen with the `textChanged()`-event. According to the documentation there is no special escape-event. So how else can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Each `QWidget` (and the `QLineEdit` is one) has a method called [`keyPressEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent). In your own subclass, you can overload it and check if `event->key()` is the Escape key. But don't forget to call the base class `keyPressEvent` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. I am solving it by implementing `keyPressEvent` in my `QMainWindow`.

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if (e->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {
        QLineEdit *focus = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(focusWidget());
        if (lineEditKeyEventSet.contains(focus)) {
            focus->clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And setting up `QSet<QLineEdit *> lineEditKeyEventSet` to contain the `QLineEdit`s that need this behavior.

```
void MainWindow::setupLineEditKeyEventList()
{
    lineEditKeyEventSet.insert(ui->lineEdit_1);
    lineEditKeyEventSet.insert(ui->lineEdit_2);
    lineEditKeyEventSet.insert(ui->lineEdit_3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement `keyPressEvent` :

```
void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
    {
        ...
    }

    QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Or implement `eventFilter` :

```
bool LineEdit::eventFilter(QObject  *obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if((LineEdit *)obj == this && event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress && ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Escape )
    {
        ...
    }

    return false;
}
```

When using the `eventFilter` approach, install the event filter in the constructor :

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Does not work. I get events at both functions but not when Esc-key is pressed. My class does not inherit directly from QLineEdit, is there a possibility somebody else eats this event? If yes, how could one suppress functionality of keyPressEvent()/eventFilter()?

Comment: Nejat: I found the Escape-event is sent to the LineEdits parent window, not to the line edit field itself...any possibility to forward it to the LineEdit object too?

Comment: Then why don't you handle the event for pressing Escape in that window?

Comment: Nejat: and then do what with this event - send it to all child widgets because one of them needs it? I can't imagine that there is no way to get Esc in a child widget...

Comment: If you need to handle it in line edit you can post an event to the child widget when you catch it in the window. You can post a key press event like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322602/qt-sending-keypressevent/24325983#24325983

Comment: Nejat: I understand this concept, but isn't this a bit complicated for such a simple task? Means an application either has to post it to _every_ child widget (which is wasting of resources when one widget is interested in the event and 99 receive it just to do nothing with it) or a functionality for registering child widgets has to be implemented so that the event is posted to the registered widgets only (which is some kind of overkill). Don't misunderstand me, I blame Qt for that, not you!